# How to remove the Border of a UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net

I can't able to remove the border of the Update panel.
 It does not support style property.

Comment: Are you trying to do it in the code behind or in the aspx ?

Comment: The UpdatePanel doesn't have a border, by default. Are you sure the border you see belongs to it?

Comment: Got It! .it was the border of fieldset inside UpdatePanel.
I got the answer. thank u.

Answer (score 0):

You could have some CSS that's affecting `<div>` elements on the page, but without seeing your code it's awfully hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the `CSS` you are using, you can try to remove the style for `<div>` generated from update panel through JavaScript.

```
document.getElementById("<%=UpdatePanel.ClientID %>").style = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UpdatePanel` control in ASP.NET 4 has been improved to support setting its style through an expando:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" style="whatever" />
```

Of course, this doesn't help if you're using a previous version of ASP.NET.

Either way it looks like you found the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Update Panel dosent have any border property, it all the feildset border which is to be set to **fieldset** `style = "border:none"`, if you dont like

Answer (score 0):

U have to use style in fieldset like

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server"> 
          <ContentTemplate> 
              <fieldset style="border:none" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change div tag as below-

```
<div style="height: 300px; width:650px; overflow-y: auto; border:dotted 1px black;">
<asp:UpdatePanel tag>    
</div>
```